# Finding Matched results in CSV

Tags: python, csv, datatables, output, match

I have my data in this format :

| Harvard | MIT |
| --- | --- |
| David | Troy |
| Siri | Charlie |
| Troy | David |
| Alexa | Cortana |
| Cortana | Man |
| Animal | David |

and I want my results to be in :

| Harvard | MIT | Output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| David | Troy | David |
| Harvard | MIT | Troy |
| David | Troy | Cortana |
| Siri | Charlie |  |
| Troy | David |  |
| Alexa | Cortana |  |
| Cortana | Man |  |

I don't care the order I get the name, just I need the list of person who are attending both institutions.
I have them stored in same csv file but different column.

**Python** is my preferred language. Or I have git bash Installed on my windows either. I need a solution.

Comment: This is not the place for you to expect others will do your work. You at least need to show some effort on your side.

Comment: Well, I've solved that issue already. Using python set and intersection method worked for me. I just needed the correct way, if i had to deal directly with csv later. Thanks for your concern though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line of code should solve your problem.

```
df['Output'] = df['Harvard'].loc[df['Harvard'].isin(df.MIT.values.tolist())]
```

You can sort the Output-column afterwards, if you want to.

Comment: `import pandas as pd`
`df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')`
`above code here` . Thanks for your Answer. I just needed the exact way and seeing this i knew, its beautiful. I solved my issue converting csv to list and using intersection method of python.